# Quickbuild in Texmaker on Catalina

Tags: texmaker, macos

I just updated my running system to macOS Catalina 10.15 and now the quickbuild in Texmaker does not work anymore. More precisely even if I use the PdfLatex command it does not create a document?

Can anyone help me with this and tell me what I need to do to get it running again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the last version of TexMaker here:

https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

and I do not have any problem now.